# Postfix Dovecot LMTP and address delimiters doesn't work

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I have a Debian server with Postfix and Dovecot. Recently I installed Sieve on Dovecot and configured Postfix to deliver emails with LMTP. Since then pure usernames don't work together with a delimiter. Delimiters only seem to get resolved when the aliases-db is involved. The log says:

```
User doesn't exist: doe-test@example.com (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Here is the basic setup with some examples

```
username: doe  
delimiter: -    
doe@example.com -> works  
john.doe@example.com -> works  
doe-test@example.com -> unknown user  
john.doe-test@example.com -> works
```

**`/etc/aliases`** :

```
john.doe: doe
```

**`/etc/postfix/main.cf`** :

```
recipient_delimiter = -
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
# All options: propagate_unmatched_extensions = canonical, virtual, alias, forward, include
propagate_unmatched_extensions =
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here isn't with Postfix but with Dovecot. Since Dovecot doesn't know about the Postfix `recipient_delimiter` it has to assume that a user query for *doe-test@example.com* really does mean “Look for user »doe-test« on domain »example.com«”.

This solution to this is fortunately trivial, simply [tell Dovecot what you told Postfix](https://wiki.dovecot.org/LMTP#Address_extension_delivery):

1. Open `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-lda.conf`
2. Uncomment the line containing `#recipient_delimiter = +` and replace the `+` by whatever (`-` in your case)
3. Profit!

## On Postfix address delivery and /etc/aliases:

The reason why `john.doe@example.com` works in your setup is because aliases lookup is done by Postfix itself *before* deciding on whether the message will be delivered at all (i.e.: LMTP is not relevant at all at this stage).

So what happens is this:

- Postfix receives a message for `john.doe-test@example.com` using its `smtpd` daemon and places it in the message queue
- The postfix `qmgr` daemon schedules the message for processing
- `qmgr` resolves the message destination using the [`trivial-rewrite`](http://www.postfix.org/trivial-rewrite.8.html) command

  - This is where address parsing and lookups are performed and therefor the recipient delimiter is used for the first time.
  - In particular Postfix will perform the following lookups on the aliases table:

    1. `john.doe-test@example.com` and `john.doe-test` (Original address)
    2. `john.doe@example.com` and `john.doe` (Address without adddress extension)
    3. (Possibly a few others depending on the address and configuration used.)
  - If the lookup succeeds it will return the new destination address and the message will be placed in the queue again.
- Eventually the message will (one way or another) end up being marked as ready for delivery (even if it bounces, that's just a special type of delivery…) and `qmgr` will schedule the appropriate command to carry out that delivery (such as [`lmtp`](http://www.postfix.org/lmtp.8.html)) – passing to it the message with its final delivery address (in our case `doe@example.com`)

  - If Postfix's `lmtp` is used for delivery a connection to the actual LMTP daemon (Dovecot) will be established and the message (with the finaly delivery address) will be passed on using the LMTP protocol.
- Dovecot's LMTP daemon will know nothing of this whole rewriting process and will simply try to deliver the message based on the final delivery address (`doe@example.com`) it receives.

Now, if we instead consider the case of `doe-test@example.com` we see that the aliases table lookup for that address will never succeed and so the delivery address will never be rewritten. Postfix will therefor end up trying to deliver a message to `doe-test@example.com` using LMTP instead.

**Shouldn't Postfix just discard the address extension before trying to deliver using LMTP?**
*Maybe*, but *not* discarding it comes with a huge benefit: Dovecot will be able to *know* about the address extension. This may not seem very useful, but processing the address extension on the Dovecot side allows for cool things such as [automatically placing messages in IMAP sub-folders using Sieve](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples#Plus_Addressed_mail_filtering).

Comment: Hi, it works like a charm. I'm still confused, why the problem only occurs with pure usernames and not with items in the alias list, but telling dovecot about the delimiter makes sense anyways.

Comment: @jochen: I've updated my answer to explain how delivery works in Postfix and why it failed when using address extensions, but now aliases in your case.